# jQuery form elements not loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm not sure why, but when I call `$(form).serialize()` it returns object within dynamically created elements.

I have this html syntax:

```
<form id="form1"></form>
<input type="text" name="formItem[0][value]" value="XX" />
<input type="text" name="formItem[INDEX][value]" value="XX" />
```

I call method to clone `input[name="formItem[0][value]"]` and replace **INDEX** with 1, so then I have form like this:

```
<form id="form1"></form>
<input type="text" name="formItem[0][value]" value="XX" />
<input type="text" name="formItem[1][value]" value="XX" />
<input type="text" name="formItem[INDEX][value]" value="XX" />
```

But then, when I call method to serialize form, there are still same count of elements -> two - but for this example:
When I submit form for first time, with no cloned input, there was `formItem[0][value]` and `formItem[INDEX][value]`, but when I call clone and then submit form, `serializeArray` method return `formItem[0][value]` and `formItem[1][value]`.
[image]

Do you have any idea, how to solve my problem?
https://jsfiddle.net/8u83h22j/2/

Comment: how do you mean? the second submit is return 3 object in my case.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it now and yeah, but when you add other input, there still are just 3 objects returned. And when you press "Run" again and clone inputs, it returns always just 2.

Comment: I don't know your problem..:(

Comment: Seems to work fine. I'm now at six inputs and it returns an array with six objects. Shouldn't it work like this?

Comment: Yeah, it should. But on my pc it returns just 2 or 3 objects :/

Comment: Maybe you can try other platform or give more information.  it worked for me, too. http://imgur.com/WjvIkSr

Comment: I have tried your fiddle and it works..? can you improve your question please

Comment: I add picture to my question, here is visible my problem - when I press "Submit", it return just 3 objects instead of 6.
I use OS X and Safari.

Comment: I got it. Safari you may choose import jquery?

Comment: Anyway, when I use Chrome on OS X, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Solved - use Chrome instead of Safari browser.